# Enabling Cookies and Redirects in TestRestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

How to I add `TestRestTemplate.HttpClientOption.ENABLE_REDIRECTS` and `TestRestTemplate.HttpClientOption.ENABLE_COOKIES` to spring-boots TestRestTemplate?

I am using spring-boot so have a TestRestTemplate configured for me automatically.

I can customise this bean before creation using `RestTemplateBuilder`.  The problem is I can't see how to add these options:

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .errorHandler(new ResponseErrorHandler() {
                    ...
                });
    }
```

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.html) has some constructors that accept these options but the problem is the bean has already been created for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `TestRestTemplate` and present it to Spring by using the `@Bean` annotation.

For example:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .errorHandler(new ResponseErrorHandler() {
                @Override
                public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {

                }
            }).build();

    return new TestRestTemplate(restTemplate, user, password, TestRestTemplate.HttpClientOption.ENABLE_REDIRECTS, TestRestTemplate.HttpClientOption.ENABLE_COOKIES);
}
```

Or, if you do not need to customise the `RestTemplate` then use the following constructor (which internally instances a `RestTemplate` for you):

```
@Bean
@Primary
public TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate() {
    return new TestRestTemplate(TestRestTemplate.HttpClientOption.ENABLE_REDIRECTS, TestRestTemplate.HttpClientOption.ENABLE_COOKIES);
}
```

**Update 1** to address this comment:

> when I run my tests, I now get the following error `org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified`

The `TestRestTemplate` provided by Spring is configured to resolve paths relative to `http://localhost:${local.server.port}`. So, when you replace the Spring provided instance with your own instance you'll either have to provide the full address (including host and port) or configure your own `TestRestTemplate` with a `LocalHostUriTemplateHandler` (you can see this code in `org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer.TestRestTemplateFactory`). Here's an example of the latter approach:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .errorHandler(new ResponseErrorHandler() {
                @Override
                public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {

                }
            }).build();

    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate =
            new TestRestTemplate(restTemplate, user, password, TestRestTemplate.HttpClientOption
                    .ENABLE_REDIRECTS, TestRestTemplate.HttpClientOption.ENABLE_COOKIES);

    // let this testRestTemplate resolve paths relative to http://localhost:${local.server.port}
    LocalHostUriTemplateHandler handler =
            new LocalHostUriTemplateHandler(applicationContext.getEnvironment(), "http");
    testRestTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(handler);

    return testRestTemplate;
}
```

With this bean configuration the following test case uses the customised `TestRestTemplate` and successfully invokes the Spring Boot app on localhost:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class RestTemplateTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ResponseEntity<String> forEntity = this.restTemplate.getForEntity("/some/endpoint", String.class);
        System.out.println(forEntity.getBody());
    }
}
```

Comment: This causes more problems.  Firstly I needed to add `@Primary` to `testRestTemplate()` ortherwise two beans were registered.  Secondly when I run my tests, I now get the following error `org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified`. I suppose spring-boot is doing more magic when creating the TestRestTemplate.

Comment: @jax apologies, I have updated the question to clarify how to use the customised `TestRestTemplate` and how to configure it if you want to use it in the same way as you would use Spring's provided `TestRestTemplate`.

Comment: I do not exactly understand in which file I need to put the customized TestRestTemplate with '@Bean' and '@Primary' annotation? Should it go to my test class?

Comment: There's a `TestRestTemplate` constructor that takes the builder, skipping a step.

Comment: You can't define `@Bean`s in test classes, but you can equally just use a `@BeforeEach` rather than have it be a bean.